# Does anyone know the what's causing "Package name is not a valid package name" when adding a new layout?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've receiving this error in every project I make, new or otherwise.

[image: Error in Android Studio]

I've attempted reinstalling Android Studio fresh without any luck and I've also scoured the Internet for the exact error and nothing seems to be coming up.

Does anyone have an idea of what's causing this error when I add a new layout to my project?

Comment: what package name did you enter at first step while creating project?

Comment: I've tried a few com.example com.nicholas and more complex ones. All resulted in the same error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As your screenshot shows,current package name is layout,but maybe you don't have a package named `layout`,so such error existed.

If you want to add a layout file to your project,you should right click **layout** folder under **res** folder,and create a layout file.

Comment: So this is the process that I follow and why I can't understand this error. I'm right clicking the layouts folder and adding the layout there.

Comment: OK so I'm an idiot and didn't realise that package name was the project's package name. However, I don't think I was to know as Android Studio kept defaulting the package name to layout. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For me, it worked otherwise. I got the same error when I right click on layout folder, but when I did right on res folder, it automatically created the layout in layout folder.

Answer (score 17):

Instead of adding the new activity by right clicking on the file labeled "layout", right click on the file labeled "res" to add a new activity and it should work fine.

Answer (score 12):

Hope this helps

Option 1:

1. Click the Project tab. From there you can see a dropdown. Click the dropdown and go to Packages and then you can see the layout folder. From there you can create another Blank Activity.

Option 2:

1. From the dropdown again go to Android. Click the java folder, you can see the package name com.example... Write it down on a paper. Then go to layout and create a blank activity. Change the package name to what you had just wrote down on the paper.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add some details to what Infamous said.
You can copy the package name from another existing activity.

```
package com.mycompany.myself.myapplication;
```

I agree, I'm surprised that Android Studio is not able to default that with the right value, given during the project creation:
Project structure/app/Flavors/defaultConfig/Application Id

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio, in the **java directory**, **select the package**, for example com.mycompany.myfirstapp, right-click, and select **New > Activity > Blank Activity.**

[image: package name is not set to a valid package name]

Answer (score 2):

1 - to find the right package name 
go to (main activity) page .

2 - First line you will see this for example :

package alqahtani.dhafer.myapp;

copy this text **alqahtani.dhafer.myapp**

3 - go to layout --> right click --> new activity --> paste package name in layout name .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just "layout" cannot be a package name check other activities and try to take that packag name on top of the file

Comment: I'm not quite following you sorry.

Answer (score 1):

When adding a new activity to my application, it shows the following problem: Package name is not set to a valid package name, and does not allow adding the activity.

** Solution 1 **: Instead of adding the new activity by right-clicking on the file named "** layout **", right click on the "** res **" file to add a new activity.

And no longer shows the problem: Package name is not set to a valid package name, this is because I could not find the package layout.

** Solution 2 **: In the field ** Package name **, put us as package ** layout ** delete it and put the full name of your application package. ** Example **:

com.mx.softmolina.example

http://blog.softmolina.com.mx/wp/2016/11/30/solucion-package-name-is-not-set-to-a-valid-package-name-agregar-nueva-actividad/

I hope it will be you useful.

Regards!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the package name **Layout** to project package name.

[image]

After changing the Package name. It will allow to finish process.

**OR**

Copy project package name from any java class and paste in **Package name** section.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same error message (`Package name is not a valid package name`) when I was trying to add a new activity. The problem was that I was trying to add a new activity to the wrong place. I was trying to add the activity (`new -> activity -> blank activity`) in the `res/layout` directory.  The solution was to add the activity in the `java/your_app` directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a layout file to your project, follow below way - 
app -> res -> New -> Acivity -> select activity which u want.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I right-clicked on the Activity node in my project explorer. If I click on the "app" root node, this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply because you are trying to create new Activity / Layout file in a wrong package. To do so, You have to navigate to ***app >> java >> firstfolder***.

Right Click on this first folder and go to ***NEW >> Activity >> EmptyActivity*** or AnyOtherTypeYouWant. Then enter the correct name for your Activity and you will face no errors.

As simple as that.